# how to test private methods using xunit C#

Tags: c#, testing, xunit

I'm using xUnit for testing for the code in C#.
I had a problem, when I test a private method, it isn't work because the method isn't public (the another classes cannot access this method).

I have a class where has a private method:

```cs
public class Calculator{
    //...
    private double DegreeToRadian(double angle)
    {
        return Math.PI * angle / 180.0;
    }
    //...
}
```

And in the test:

```cs
public class TestCalculator{

    [Fact]
    public void ConvertDegreeToRadian()
    {
        // Arrange
        Calculator _calculator = new Calculator();
    
        // Act
        double angle = 90;
        double expected = angle * Math.PI / 180;
        double result = _calculator.DegreeToRadian(angle);
    
        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(expected, result);

    }
}
```

Is there a way to test in a private method?

Comment: This is usually recommended against, which is why it isn't easy to do. You either need to call it using reflection, or make it available in some way, usually by making it public. Why do you need to test it? Since it is private, it's an implementation detail.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes, my first thing I thought is put public method instead of private. Btw this is just a homework for school. My teacher said I should implement a classe, where there are some private methods, and he wants that I test this class.

Comment: In my opinion; If your teacher is teaching you to test private methods, he's either trying to teach you that it's painful, or that reflection is painful, or he's teaching you the wrong thing. There is a reason you can't easily test private methods, it's recommended against and most people try to avoid having to do it. (yes, it sometimes has to be done, but so does leaping from a building on fire, it's not something you want to make a habit of)

Comment: The _bigger_ question is why a _calculator_ has a `private`  function for converting _degrees to radians_ in the first place.  Even my $1 calculator I bought from _Walmart_ allows me to do that

Comment: @Matato Exposing private methods just to make them testable is also recommended against.

Comment: @MickyD Pratically I use mvvm for just practice and for school. This class `Calculator` there's a `public` method and it use some `private` methods like `double DegreeToRadian(double angle)`.

Comment: @TechInquisitor ok.

Comment: _"This class Calculator there's a public method and it use some private methods like double DegreeToRadian(double angle)."_ - if the `private` methods are called indirectly by the `public` methods then there is no need to test  the former directly. If you find you have `private` methods that are never called by `public` methods then it may be a design problem possibly involving orphaned code

Comment: @MickyD alright, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should test all your code but private methods are tested implicitly.

That is, your code somehow affects the output of some public method.

If it doesn't, then it is never executed. If it does, then you test it by calling the public method and testing against the output that is affected by the private one.

The only exception to that rule, is testing internal classes as it is an in between visibility option.